# Strange PTypeInfo name for generic integer

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I need to do a "smart" detection of a generic type and return as a string, but at the moment i don't understand why delphi put some strange identification on the PTypeInfo.Name property.

What i have so far is this:

```
program SO_29674887;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.TypInfo;

type
  TypeResolver = class
  strict private
    class function ReCast<T>(const AValue) : T;
  public
    class function Format<T>(const AValue : T) : string;
  end;

  Compare = class
  public
    class function IsEqual<A;B>(const AVal : A; BVal : B) : string;
  end;

{ TypeResolver }

class function TypeResolver.ReCast<T>(const AValue): T;
begin
  Result := T(AValue);
end;

class function TypeResolver.Format<T>(const AValue: T): string;
var Info : PTypeInfo;
begin
  Info := TypeInfo(T);

  Result := 'undefined';

  if(Info.Kind = tkInteger) then
    begin
      if(Info.Name = GetTypeName(TypeInfo(Byte))) then
        Result := IntToStr(ReCast<Byte>(AValue))
      else if(Info.Name = GetTypeName(TypeInfo(ShortInt))) then
        Result := IntToStr(ReCast<ShortInt>(AValue))
      else if(Info.Name = GetTypeName(TypeInfo(SmallInt))) then
        Result := IntToStr(ReCast<SmallInt>(AValue))
      else if(Info.Name = GetTypeName(TypeInfo(Integer))) then
        Result := IntToStr(ReCast<Integer>(AValue));
    end;

  Result := Info.Name + ':' + Result;
end;

{ Compare }

class function Compare.IsEqual<A, B>(const AVal: A; BVal: B): string;
begin
  Result := Format('%s = %s', [
    TypeResolver.Format<A>(AVal),
    TypeResolver.Format<B>(BVal)]);
end;

var PAUSE : string;

begin
  try
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
    WriteLn(Compare.IsEqual(0, 255));
    WriteLn(Compare.IsEqual(-127, 127));
    WriteLn(Compare.IsEqual(0, 65535));
    WriteLn(Compare.IsEqual(-32768, 32767));
    WriteLn(Compare.IsEqual(0, 4294967295));
    WriteLn(Compare.IsEqual(-2147483648, 2147483647));
    Readln(PAUSE);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

What happens here is that instead of give me the actual type name of the integer, delphi gives me strange identifier like :2, :4, :6, etc.

For instance:

```
Compare.IsEqual(0, 255); //Gives Info.Name = :2, Byte
Compare.IsEqual(-127, 127); //Gives Info.Name = ShortInt, :4
Compare.IsEqual(0, 65535); //Gives Info.Name = :6, Word
Compare.IsEqual(-32768, 32767); //Gives Info.Name = SmallInt, :8
Compare.IsEqual(0, 4294967295); //Gives Info.Name = :01, Cardinal
Compare.IsEqual(-2147483648, 2147483647); //Gives Info.Name = Integer, :21
```

So my question is how i can find the right type to cast if it seems to me that delphi doesn't provide any clue of the actual type when he deliver those identifiers and why exactly it gives those odd identifiers.

Comment: Er, this is not reproducible here. Please provide an MCVE.  A complete program, console app, single .dpr file.

Comment: It's also surely a mistake to use a name to work out the size of an integral type. Not all 32 bit signed integers are call `Integer`. The type info already contains the size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my reproduction, somewhat shorter.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.TypInfo;

type
  TypeResolver = class
  public
    class function Format<T>(const AValue : T) : string;
  end;

class function TypeResolver.Format<T>(const AValue: T): string;
var
  Info: PTypeInfo;
begin
  Info := TypeInfo(T);
  Result := Info.Name;
end;

begin
  Writeln(TypeResolver.Format(0));
  Writeln(TypeResolver.Format<Byte>(0));
  Writeln(TypeResolver.Format(255));
  Readln;
end.
```

In XE2 the output is:

```
:3
Byte
Byte
```

In XE6 and later the output is:

```
ShortInt
Byte
Byte
```

It looks as though the earlier versions of Delphi create a private type with an unspeakable name when inferring from a literal of `0`. I cannot say why that should be so. Since the behaviour has changed, one can only assume that the Embarcadero engineers made the change to fix what they deemed to be a defect.

In other words, it would seem that the behaviour that you are observing is a bug.

My hypothesis that a private type is created is backed up by this program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.TypInfo;

type
  TypeResolver = class
  public
    class function Format<T>(const AValue : T) : string;
  end;

class function TypeResolver.Format<T>(const AValue: T): string;
var
  Info: PTypeInfo;
  TypeData: PTypeData;
begin
  Info := TypeInfo(T);
  Result := Info.Name;
  if Info.Kind=tkInteger then begin
    TypeData := GetTypeData(Info);
    Result := Result + ', min = ' + IntToStr(TypeData.MinValue) + 
      ', max = ' + IntToStr(TypeData.MaxValue);
  end;
end;

begin
  Writeln(TypeResolver.Format(0));
  Readln;
end.
```

On XE2 the output is:

```
:3, min = 0, max = 127
```

On XE6 the output is:

```
ShortInt, min = -128, max = 127
```

So I think that this is an issue with generic type inference, that we can probably ascribe to a bug fixed in XE6.

I don't have any advice for how you should work around this because I don't know your actual problem. That said, comparing type names is generally something that is best avoided if possible.

Comment: my example was build with xe6 so perhaps thats why I didn't experience the bug. But anyway stick to TValue

Comment: ok thanks for your time, thanks to the lack of any logical explanation i suspected it could be a bug.

Answer (score 4):

It seems for me like you are trying to invent TValue which is  located in RTTI.pas

I've rewritten your example using TValue.

Place a TMemo on a form and the following code:

```
uses
  RTTI;

type
  TypeResolver = class
  public
    class function ReCast<T>(const AValue): T;
    class function Format<T>(const AValue: T): string;
  end;

  Compare = class
  public
    class function IsEqual<A; B>(const AValA: A; const AValB: B): string;
  end;

class function Compare.IsEqual<A, B>(const AValA: A; const AValB: B): string;
begin
  Result := Format('%s = %s', [TypeResolver.Format<A>(AValA), TypeResolver.Format<B>(AValB)]);
end;

{ TypeResolver }

class function TypeResolver.ReCast<T>(const AValue): T;
begin
  Result := T(AValue);
end;

class function TypeResolver.Format<T>(const AValue: T): string;
begin
  Result := TValue.From(AValue).TypeInfo.Name;
end;

procedure TForm13.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Compare.IsEqual(0, 255));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Compare.IsEqual(-127, 127));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Compare.IsEqual(0, 65535));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Compare.IsEqual(-32768, 32767));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Compare.IsEqual(0, 4294967295));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Compare.IsEqual(-2147483648, 2147483647));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Compare.IsEqual(Form13, Memo1));
end;
```

I belive it does the thick for you?

Here is the output of above:

```
ShortInt = Byte
ShortInt = ShortInt
ShortInt = Word
SmallInt = SmallInt
ShortInt = Cardinal
Integer = Integer
TForm13 = TMemo
```

Comment: thx for ur attention, tried what you posted but still im getting the same odd name for some types, e.g `Compare.IsEqual(0, 255)` doesn't result `ShortInt = Byte` as you mention, instead gives me `:6 = Byte`. I though it could be a problem with my delphi instalation so i tried in other machines and got the same result.

Comment: @kabstergo How about that MCVE?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan made a console app, here it is https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_Inqdi8y8zzWXowX0pyT2hFeWs&authuser=0

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful. I've added an answer for you.